# full path of libm.a in gcc version 9

Tags: gcc

based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925678/location-of-c-standard-library
**gcc --print-file-name=libm.a**
return:
**/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a**

---

However I cannot found it.
In current directory(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9): I do `ls` command, return following:

```
cc1          crtfastmath.o      finclude           libcaf_single.a  libgfortran.spec  liblsan.so              libobjc_gc.so       libsupc++.a
cc1plus      crtoffloadbegin.o  include            libcc1.so        libgomp.a         liblsan_preinit.o       libquadmath.a       libtsan.a
collect2     crtoffloadend.o    libasan.a          libgcc.a         libgomp.so        liblto_plugin.so        libquadmath.so      libtsan.so
crtbegin.o   crtoffloadtable.o  libasan.so         libgcc_eh.a      libgomp.spec      liblto_plugin.so.0      libsanitizer.spec   libubsan.a
crtbeginS.o  crtprec32.o        libasan_preinit.o  libgcc_s.so      libitm.a          liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0  libssp_nonshared.a  libubsan.so
crtbeginT.o  crtprec64.o        libatomic.a        libgcov.a        libitm.so         libobjc.a               libstdc++.a         lto-wrapper
crtend.o     crtprec80.o        libatomic.so       libgfortran.a    libitm.spec       libobjc.so              libstdc++.so        lto1
crtendS.o    f951               libbacktrace.a     libgfortran.so   liblsan.a         libobjc_gc.a            libstdc++fs.a       plugin
```

---

only **finclude**, **include**, **plugin** are directory. I already checked libm.a is not there.

Why bother, because base on this link.(https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_17.html)
I should able to do the following command if I found out the proper libm.a full path.

```
gcc -Wall calc.c /usr/lib/libm.a -o calc
```

However the following command still works.

```
gcc -Wall calc.c -lm -o calc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a

The '../' in the file name gcc gave you means that you go up to the parent directory.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
= /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
= /usr/lib/gcc/../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
= /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
```

So, libm is actually located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a`.